# Record screen with flutter in the background as a stream

Tags: flutter, video, stream, screen-recording

So I want to create an app for android *and* ios that allow the user to stream their screen to another place, I'm thinking something like google cast and the likes

I can easily find flutter screen recording, for android and ios in one package, but there doesn't seem to be one that lets me capture the screen to a *stream* of some sort (i do NOT want it saved as a file)

I'm thinking I could maybe create my own package for this, in which case, is there any kind of "standard" video stream in a flutter that would widely be accepted to just work, like a google cast API or whatever? From what I can find, there isn't...

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. In general, opinion based questions such as "what's the best tool for __x__" are frowned upon but in this case, I think there's a good question. Maybe add how/where you've already searched and what's wrong with what you're finding. e.g. "I've searched google for 'flutter to stream' and all the results are cat videos"

Comment: I don't mean like "whats the best way to record the screen like this?" i'm asking how to do it at all, cause i can't find a tool that lets me record the screen and stream it to somewhere live, only save it to a file

Comment: After some intense thinking, i realize the "standard video stream" is probably just a regular stream in the format of just [general internet video streaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming) i guess, so yeah i'll probably just do that i guess?

Comment: I don't have sufficient experience in it to give a full answer. I did watch a good bit of this video and think it may be going the right direction. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ovbspHZJ9b0

Comment: still searching solution of screen stream recording in flutter, any suggestion?

Comment: any updates here?

Answer (score 0):

There's a Flutter plugin ([flutter_screen_recording](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screen_recording)) that you can use for screen capture on Android and iOS. Though this requires Android SDK 21+ and iOS 10+.

To start screen recording

```dart
bool started = FlutterScreenRecording.startRecordScreen(videoName);
```

then to end the recording

```dart
if(started){
  String path = FlutterScreenRecording.stopRecordScreen;
  debugPrint('Screen recording path: $path');
}
```